# Cant' seed files to my Rails app on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to seed my app on Heroku. I use a seed like:

```
Word.create 
  :name => "Name", 
  :description =>"Im a description", 
  :example => "Im an example", 
  :icon => File.open("public/images/exp/example.png"), 
  :audio => File.open("public/sounds/example.mp3")
```

This works great on my dev machine but I can't manage to run it flawlessly on Heroku (it does create a new record, just it doesn't upload an image).

I run 'heroku run rake db:seed'

and I get

```
/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin/rake:
```

I tried updating to Ruby 2.0.0, I was using 1.9.3 previously; I've done some research and some people claim to have the same problem but solved it by running:

```
heroku config:set PATH=bin:vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
```

well... it didn't work for me.

I'm using Rails 4 by the way.

Comment: if I remember correctly things you put in `public/` will also get included in asset pipeline meaning your images will have a versioning hash on it too. Either I don't think people normally persist blob in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Heroku is a read-only filesystem, so you cannot upload images. Probably this will help

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/read-only-filesystem

Comment: Even if you are on a writeable stack it's not good practice because the filesystem is "ephemeral". It lasts only as long as the dyno instance & each instance is separate. It's actually why you need to use Memcached service instead of just using local Rails caching. Sweeping cache would only affect the single dyno, all others would have old data.

Comment: I guess this has changed since then?